# applet while returning response to servlet not able to set parameter more that 2 MB

Tags: java, servlets, parameters, applet

I am using Applet to perform PDF signing using DSC but when my pdf size increase more than 2MB its not able to send signed data back to server.
Is there any applet Memory size issue.
JRE being used is 1.8_45 
Even i tried to increase size of my applet but it didnot effect.

My piece of code is below where i am getting error :here i am trrying to send  using dscData Parameter :

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(dscRequest);
            //System.out.println("\n dscRequest in AbstractDSCApplet::"+dscRequest );
            String encodedData = new String(Base64Utils.encode(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
            encodedData = URLEncoder.encode(encodedData);
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write((new StringBuilder("dscData=")).append(encodedData).toString());
```

But on servlet i am getting nullpointer exception at below line:

```
String inputData = request.getParameter("dscData");
```

Do help me if any one have the idea regading this. it helps me alot to resolve a big issue.